# How to provide credentials to JCIFS in TeamCity for the Deployer Plug In?

Tags: teamcity, jcifs

Using the [Deployer plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin), I'm getting this exception:

> [13:37:11]Step 2/2: Copy Files (SMB Deployer)
>
> [13:37:11][Step 2/2] Starting upload via SMB to \devwebserver\WebApps\TCTest\TCTestDeploy
>
> [13:37:11][Step 2/2] jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
>
> [13:37:11][Step 2/2] Step Copy Files (SMB Deployer) failed

Based in [these instructions](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Build+Agent+Startup+Properties#ConfiguringBuildAgentStartupProperties-BuildAgentIsRunAsService)  I added the following entries to the agent launcher (C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\launcher\conf\wrapper.conf) and also (by mistake) to ntlm-config.properties:

> jcifs.smb.client.username=**username**
>
> jcifs.smb.client.password=**password**

However I continue to get that exception.

We do not want to put the credentials in the build step directly for security reasons.

What do I need to to do so that the SMB Deployer uses the credentials in the configuration given?

Comment: Is it NetApp jcifs share?

Comment: I don't know.  That's why I asked.  Is it?

Comment: You asked "how to provide credentials properly" but you haven't specified what kind of network share it is. If it is a NetApp share, then try this http://community.netapp.com/t5/Network-Storage-Protocols-Discussions/Cannot-connect-to-a-CIFS-share-from-jCIFS/m-p/30053#M2682

Comment: It's a Windows share.  As per the linked reference  I gave:  SMB Deployer - Allows uploading files to Windows shares via the SMB protocol.- Implementation relies on the JCIFS library. To configure the JCIFS client using system properties, update the TeamCity Agent startup properties .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up putting the credentials in a template at the root level, and setting parameters for the other fields.  That way every project can customize the working folders and such, while using the appropriate service credentials securely.